# Import and transpile external library with Webpack and typescript-loader

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have project that uses Webpack and Typescript (typescript-loader). My tsconfig.json file is pretty straightforward and is set to target ES5:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./public/dist",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
    }
}
```

The webpack configuration file contains the following rule for my typescript files:

```
module: {
    rules: [{
       test: /\.ts?$/,
       loader: 'ts-loader'
    }]
},
```

All my project files are being compiled as intended to ES5 code and run fine. However, in one of my TS files I import a library installed through NPM: `import * as striptags from "striptags"`

The problem is that this file is not transpiled into ES5 and ends up with `const` and `let` keywords in my bundle that is targeted at ES5 devices. This causes JS errors.

How can I import the external *striptags* library and transpile it to ES5 so it doesn't break my client-side code?

I'm using TypeScript 2.6.1 and Webpack 3.10.0. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that I did not read the readme of the [striptags](https://www.npmjs.com/package/striptags) library correctly. It states that you should use the 2.x.x branch for ES5 support. Everything works fine now.

Comment: Either that or you can use a transpiler to convert ES2015+ code which is what scripttags is using. In case interested to try it out with latest scripttags, check this change to use babel-loader : https://github.com/rakcheru/webpack-bootstrap/commit/11faa5757701422715ff76f1536e3a4a67020f68 . Please do note that the change excludes node_modules. That needs to be removed in your case.